# Is a charged-coupled-devices tag okay? If so, what would be good usage guidance for it?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag, tagging

I've just added the new tag [charge-coupled-devices](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charge-coupled-devices) to [How often are electron-multiplying CCDs used in telescope focal planes? Will Nancy Grace Roman be the first use in a space telescope?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/41035/7982) since that's the primary target of the question. I think we've had several questions before that are primarily about how CCDs work and how they are operated in astrophotography situations.

I did not add it to its companion question [Why does Nancy Grace Roman = 100 × Hubble? Why is the new space telescopes wide field camera so much wider than the old one's?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/41036/7982) because while it involves what's at the focal plane, it's not specifically about the design and operation of charged-coupled devices.

We don't have a `focal-plane` or `instrumentation` tag, and [instruments](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instruments) seems to general and more about a larger assembly than a CCD and its associated electronics.

Shall we keep this tag? If so, what would good usage guidance for it be?

Answer (score 3):

The only problem with the tag as-is is that it doesn't appear when you search for "CCD" :-)

Also, would a future "CMOS" tag be appropriate, or would an all-encompassing "imaging devices" or "photon sensors" tag be better?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know what you mean about CCD and I had thought about using that instead, it's not too late to switch to that, [charge-coupled-devices](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charge-coupled-devices) only has two questions. In [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/303080) we can find [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/303080) and it seems to me that both tags must exist and be used first before any synonymization can occur, but I'm no expert.

Comment: So for now I think we should choose whichever one is most likely to be typed by someone hunting for such a tag. That's why I wouldn't suggest "imaging devices" or "photon sensor" or "CMOS" as a main tag; I thing fewer people will start typing those and looking for the auto-complete.

Answer (score 2):

+3/-0 votes on the question so far and no negative comments; it seems like the tag is okay.